# Replacement for gallery_shortcode function not taking all attributes

Tags: shortcode, gallery, callbacks

I have the following custom function to replace the `gallery_shortcode` function from core. It hooks in at the beginning and works.

**The problem** is that I can't get my custom key/values from the gallery shortcode in there. I receive them in the core function, but they don't get passed into my custom function. I can't really investigate what's going wrong or where they get missing, because i don't get any `print_r` output for `$attr` inside my custom function. Any ideas?

*Note: I added comments for everything I changed from the core to my custom function.*

```
function modified_post_gallery( $attr ) 
{
    // I can't get any output from the following
    echo '<pre>'; 
            print_r( $attr ); 
    echo '</pre>';
    // But: i get the expected output if i place the same line inside the core function: 
    /root/wp-include/media.php line 759 and get the actual output including all custom key/values.

    global $post, $wp_locale;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    $output = '';

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) 
    {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( ! $attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    // extract result from user input & defaults
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
         'order'        => 'ASC'
        ,'orderby'      => 'menu_order ID'
        ,'id'           => $post->ID
        ,'itemtag'      => 'span' // CHANGED
        ,'icontag'      => 'span' // CHANGED
        ,'captiontag'   => 'span' // CHANGED
        ,'columns'      => 3
        ,'size'         => 'thumbnail'
        ,'include'      => ''
        ,'exclude'      => ''
        ,'class'        => '' // ADDED
        ,'test'
    ), $attr ) );

    $id = intval( $id );
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty( $include ) ) 
    {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array( 
             'include'          => $include
            ,'post_status'      => 'inherit'
            ,'post_type'        => 'attachment'
            ,'post_mime_type'   => 'image'
            ,'order'            => $order
            ,'orderby'          => $orderby 
        ) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) 
        {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } 
    elseif ( !empty( $exclude ) ) 
    {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array( 
             'post_parent'      => $id
            ,'exclude'          => $exclude
            ,'post_status'      => 'inherit'
            ,'post_type'        => 'attachment'
            ,'post_mime_type'   => 'image'
            ,'order'            => $order
            ,'orderby'          => $orderby 
        ) );
    } 
    else 
    {
        $attachments = get_children( array( 
             'post_parent'      => $id
            ,'post_status'      => 'inherit'
            ,'post_type'        => 'attachment'
            ,'post_mime_type'   => 'image'
            ,'order'            => $order
            ,'orderby'          => $orderby 
        ) );
    }

    // No attachments, so abort
    if ( empty( $attachments ) )
        return '';

    // RSS/Atom
    if ( is_feed() ) 
    {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link( $att_id, $size, true )."\n";

        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape( $itemtag );
    $captiontag = tag_escape( $captiontag );
    $columns = intval( $columns );
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor( 100/$columns ) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = 'gallery-'.$instance;

    $gallery_div = '';

    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );

    $gallery_div = '<div id="'.$selector.'" class="gallery galleryid-'.$id.' gallery-columns-'.$columns.' gallery-size-'.$size_class.'">';

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) 
    {
        $class = $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 ? ' last' : ''; // ADDED for the single item/image

        $link = isset( $attr['link'] ) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, false, false ) : wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $size, true, false );

        $output .= '<'.$itemtag.' class="gallery-item '.$class.'">'; // ADDED class
        $output .= '<'.$icontag.' class="gallery-icon">'.$link.'</'.$icontag.'>';
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) )
        {
            $output .= '<'.$captiontag.' class="wp-caption-text gallery-caption">';
            $output .= wptexturize( $attachment->post_excerpt );
            $output .= '</'.$captiontag.'>';
        }
        $output .= '</'.$itemtag.'>';
    }
    $output .= ''."\n";

    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'modified_post_gallery', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
function modified_post_gallery( $blank = NULL, $attr ) 
{
    echo '<pre>'; 
            print_r( $attr ); 
    echo '</pre>';
}
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'modified_post_gallery', 10, 2);
?>
```

In media.php it shows the filter like this:

```
// Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template.
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
```

Its passing two variables not one and $attr is on the second variable.

Comment: Another copy/paste error ... my callback function is added exactly with `,10, 2`. Sorry, I edit my Q.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Look at the parameters you pass to the modified_post_gallery function. Define it with a null first parameter like in the code here, and it should work.